# How to install Ejabberd Custom Module

Tags: module, xmpp, ejabberd

I have written a ejabbed custom module but i am not able to install it
According to ejabbed module doc we have to put module files in $HOME/.ejabberd-modules then use  ejabberdctl module_check to check the module but i am getting error
Error : not available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your are following the instructions from https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/extending-ejabberd/modules/#managing-your-own-modules

Did you create the spec file, as mentioned in this paragraph?

> and creating a specification file in YAML format as
>   mod_mysupermodule.spec (see examples from ejabberd-contrib). From that
>   point you should see it as available module.

Comment: Thanks I figured it out I had placed module files in wrong directory

Comment: So, did that solve your problem? If so, you should mark the question as answered.